# HTML5 Canvas Tileset drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Something like I am have tileset - http://flashpunk.net/img/tut/swordguy.png

And my drawing code is - http://jsfiddle.net/WnjB6/

But how to do something like - drawTile(x, y, tile, width, height);

Now need to set tileX and tileY on tile, but how to do only one tile need to set and draw tiles from all tileset?

Something like now need tileX = 3, tileY = 1, but I am need - tile = 8 and draw same tile.
'http://flashpunk.net/img/tut/swordguyframes.png

How to do something like?

Thanks for help and sorry for my bad English language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know there are 6 tiles in a row, so you can do it like this:

```
var drawTile = function(x, y, tile, width, height) {
    context.drawImage(image, (tile % 6) * width, Math.floor(tile / 6) * height, width, height, x, y, width, height);
};
```

So passing in `6` will go to the first tile in the second row, etc.

Here's an example, it cycles through all the tiles:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jrjyq/

Comment: Very thanks Simon! but I am have one more question. How to calculate how much tiles is in my tileset?

Comment: You just have to count. Or if you know the height/width and how large each tile is, you can divide. For instance swordguy.png is 288 pixels wide and the tiles are 48 pixels wide, 288/48 = 6

Comment: walking         if (i > 11) i = 6;